# iptables does not add/list PREROUTING rules

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm trying to add [all of the anti-DDoSing rules from JavaPipe](https://javapipe.com/ddos/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/) after [removing UFW from my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275998/can-i-uninstall-ufw-completely) and [deleting all of the ufw chains](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531446/how-do-i-remove-all-the-ufw-chains-from-iptables) (though the referenced answer didn't work. I had to run `iptables -F` and `iptables -X` with no parameters).

```
### 1: Drop invalid packets ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP  

### 2: Drop TCP packets that are new and are not SYN ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP 

### 3: Drop SYN packets with suspicious MSS value ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP  

### 4: Block packets with bogus TCP flags ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP  

### 5: Block spoofed packets ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP  

### 6: Drop ICMP (you usually don't need this protocol) ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DROP  

### 7: Drop fragments in all chains ### 
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -f -j DROP  

### 8: Limit connections per source IP ### 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 111 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset  

### 9: Limit RST packets ### 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP  

### 10: Limit new TCP connections per second per source IP ### 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/s --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP  

### 11: Use SYNPROXY on all ports (disables connection limiting rule) ### 
# Hidden - unlock content above in "Mitigating SYN Floods With SYNPROXY" section

### SSH brute-force protection ### 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP  

### Protection against port scanning ### 
/sbin/iptables -N port-scanning 
/sbin/iptables -A port-scanning -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN 
/sbin/iptables -A port-scanning -j DROP
```

When I type `iptables -S` after this, I only see a few of these rules.

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N port-scanning
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 111 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A port-scanning -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
-A port-scanning -j DROP
```

If I type [iptables -t nat -L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479879/how-to-check-prerouting-list-from-iptable-in-linux), I can see none of these rules.

```
# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How do I get a list of all iptables rules for all tables?

Comment: It does not make sense to me that you add your rules to the mangle table. Just add them to the INPUT chain. You can not see the rules because you didn't specify the mangle table. Increase your SSH brute force timeout to many thousands of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the solution that I chose, but this is close enough of a link to warrant a solution.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-list-all-iptables-rules-in-linux/